# Getting last two rows in a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I am creating a list of lines in a text file like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\FileToSearch.txt")
                .Where(x => !x.EndsWith("999999999999"));
```

and looping through the lines like this

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{ 
    if (lineCounter == 1)
    {
        outputResults.Add(oData.ToCanadianFormatFileHeader());
    }
    else if (lineCounter == 2)
    {
        outputResults.Add(oData.ToCanadianFormatBatchHeader());
    }
    else
    {
        oData.FromUsLineFormat(line);
        outputResults.Add(oData.ToCanadianLineFormat());

    }
    lineCounter = lineCounter + 1;
    textBuilder += (line + "<br>");
}
```

Similary like I access the first two rows I would like to access the last and second last row individually

Comment: I've suggested an edit that adds the C# tag to this.  It's a question about text file processing using C# - asp.net doesn't really come into the equation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you can take advantage of LINQ once again:

```
var numberOfLinesToTake = 2;
var lastTwoLines = lines
     .Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Count() - numberOfLinesToTake))
     .Take(numberOfLinesToTake);

var secondToLastLine = lastTwoLines.First();
var lastLine = lastTwoLines.Last();
```

Or, if you want to retrieve them individually:

```
var lastLine = lines.Last();
var secondToLastLine = 
    lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Count() - 2)).Take(1).First();
```

I added `.First()` to the end, because `.Take(1)` will return an array containing one item, which we then grab with `First()`. This can probably be optimized.

Again, you might want to familiarize yourself with LINQ since it's a real time-saver sometimes.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the `.Take()` really necessary here? Won't the `.Skip()` return everything but the last two anwyay?

Comment: @KileyNaro yes `.Skip()` would return everything that's needed. I added `.Take()` to make the concept more explicit. In my second example, `.Take(1)` definitely is required.

Answer (score 0):

This one of the problems of using **var** when it's not appropriate.

ReadAllLines returns an array of strings:  **string[]**

You can get the length of the array and index backwards from the end.